# Deciding the order of an entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

[image]

This is an exercise from Conway that I am stuck at. For (a) I can't understand the hint? How does the inequality in the hint holds? And what does it mean by the "maximum value?"

For (b) I think I have to use the definition of limit infimum, but can't proceed... Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

(a) "maximum value" should be "**minimum** value".

If the order of $f$ is $\lambda $ and $\beta >\lambda $, 
$$
|f(z)|<\exp(|z|^\beta )$$
holds for all $z$ with $|z|$ sufficiently large. By Cauchy's estimate
\begin{align}
|c_n|&\le \frac{M(r)}{r^n} \quad (M(r)=\max_{|z|=r}|f(z)|)\\
&\le \frac{1}{r^n}\exp(r^\beta ).
\end{align}
Taking $r=(n/\beta )^{1/\beta }$ we have \begin{align}
|c_n|\le \left(\frac{n}{\beta }\right)^{-\frac{n}{\beta}}\exp\left(\frac{n}{\beta }\right).\tag{1}
\end{align}
for sufficiently large $n$. Note that $\left(\frac{n}{\beta }\right)^{-\frac{n}{\beta}}\exp\left(\frac{n}{\beta }\right)$ is the minimum value of $r^{-n}\exp(r^\beta )$. From $(1)$ we have $$
\frac{-\log |c_n|}{n\log n}\ge \frac{1}{\beta }\left(1-\frac{1+\log \beta }{\log n}\right)\ge \frac{1}{2\beta }
$$
for sufficiently large $n$. This implies $\alpha >0.$

(b) If $\alpha =\liminf_{n\to \infty} \frac{-\log |c_n|}{n\log n}$, by the definition of $\lim \inf$ there is an integer $p$ such that $$
\alpha -\varepsilon < \frac{-\log |c_n|}{n\log n}$$
for $n>p$. This leads to
\begin{align}
-(\alpha -\varepsilon )\log n&> \frac{1}{n}\log |c_n|,\\
n^{-(\alpha -\varepsilon )}&>|c_n|^{\frac{1}{n}}.
\end{align}
Hence we have \begin{align}
|f(z)|&\le \sum_{n=0}^\infty |c_n|r^n=\sum_{n=0}^p |c_n|r^n+\sum_{n=p+1}^\infty |c_n|r^n\\
&\le \left(\sum_{n=0}^p |c_n|\right)r^p+\sum_{n=p+1}^\infty \left(\frac{r}{n^{\alpha -\varepsilon }}\right)^n.
\end{align}

Comment: Shouldn't we have $|c_n|\leq\frac{M(r)n!}{r^n}$ ?

Comment: @Oğuzhan Kılıç  $|f^{(n)}(0)|$ will be $|f^{(n)}(0)|\le \frac{M(r)n!}{r^n}$. But $|c_n|$ is less than or equal to$\frac{M(r)}{r^n}$.